# Problem to connect a laravel GC App Engine to GC SQL postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I try to connect my laravel app (stored on google cloud App Engine) to my postgresql database (stored on google cloud SQL).

This is the error : `SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select * from "roles")`

I don't found my error, and many solutions founded is for mysql (and don't work in my case).

You find the app.yaml here.

```
runtime: php81
env: standard

runtime_config:
 document_root: public


handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js))$
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: app-id:zone:instance=tcp:5432

env_variables:
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: my_app_key
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: file
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
  DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_PORT: 5432
  DB_DATABASE: postgres
  DB_USERNAME: instance
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/app-id:zone:instance
  LOG_CHANNEL: stderr
  JWT_SECRET: my-jwt-secret
```

I tried to replace the DB_HOST by *127.0.0.1*, *public_ip* and *private_ip*, but I have no result :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show how you connect to the DB in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following env variables:

```yaml
  ## for MYSQL, use DB_SOCKET:
  ## for PostgreSQL, use DB_HOST:
  DB_HOST: "/cloudsql/YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME"
```